# How to interpret/compile Swift at runtime

Tags: ios, swift

In Apple's educational app **Swift Playgrounds** on iOS, users can enter `Swift` code and have it executed at runtime. Somewhat similar to `Swift` **REPL**, with the difference that it's running inside an app.

**My question:** can we "normal" developers do that, too? Or is Apple using a runtime-compiler we don't have access to?

Comment: You should learn how to use LLVM itself.  Swift is a language, which is "backed by" the LLVM/Clang compiler.  So, you should make a C/C++ program that compiles source code and compile it against the Swift version of Clang/LLVM.  Also there are some libraries by a 3rd-party to allow one to use Swift instead of C++ to compile things!! https://lowlevelbits.org/how-to-use-llvm-api-with-swift/

Comment: I would probably start by inspecting the REPL (open) source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, guys! I'll have a look at how to use LLVM inside a C++ or Swift program - that should do the trick.